# Return a node's parent that is exactly below the root

Tags: python, tree

I have a general tree that might look like this:

[image: Tree Image]

I want to write a function *MyFunc(tree,tree_element)*
that will return the element's parent. But not the immediate parent, but a parent that is exactly one level **below** the root.
In case of the attached tree:

```
MyFunc(tree,'Dasani')
```

will return 'Coke', while:

```
MyFunc(tree,'Zero Sugar')
```

will return 'Pepsi'

I was able to write two functions.
First returns the immediate parent:

```
class tree:
    def __init__(self, key):
            self.data = key
            self.left = None
            self.right = None

    def parent_search(self, root, child_node):
        if  root :
            if root.left and root.left.data== child_node:
                return root.data
            if root.right and root.right.data== child_node:
                return root.data
            elif root:
                return self.parent_search(root.left, child_node) or self.parent_search(root.right, child_node)

root = tree('Beverage') 
root.left = tree('Pepsi') 
root.right = tree('Coke') 
root.left.left = tree('Zero Sugar') 
root.left.right = tree('Cherry Pepsi') 
root.right.left = tree('Sport Drinks')
root.right.left.left = tree('Powerade')
root.right.left.right = tree('Dasani')
root.right.left.left.left = tree('Powerade w/Sugar')

print(root.parent_search(root,'Dasani'))
```

The second returns the whole path all the way up to the root:

```
def printAncestors(root, target): 

    if root == None: 
        return False 

    if root.data == target: 
        return True 

    if (printAncestors(root.left, target) or 
        printAncestors(root.right, target)): 
        print root.data, 
        return True

     return False
printAncestors(root, 'Dasani')
```

However, I need something in between that will return only one element that is exactly one level below the root.
I can calculate the height of the tree from a leaf in question to the root. Then I was thinking to return an element that is height-1 above the leaf but am not sure that it's the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is to pass the path to root to each level of recursion, and then return the entire path, then you can extract whatever part of the path you need, like:

#### Code:

```
def parent_search(self, child_node, path_so_far=()):
    path_so_far += self.data,
    if (self.left and self.left.data == child_node or
            self.right and self.right.data == child_node):
        return path_so_far
    return (
        self.left and self.left.parent_search(child_node, path_so_far) or
        self.right and self.right.parent_search(child_node, path_so_far)
    )
```

#### Test Code:

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.data = key
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def parent_search(self, child_node, path_so_far=()):
        path_so_far += self.data,
        if (self.left and self.left.data == child_node or
                self.right and self.right.data == child_node):
            return path_so_far
        return (
            self.left and self.left.parent_search(child_node, path_so_far) or
            self.right and self.right.parent_search(child_node, path_so_far)
        )


root = Tree('Beverage')
root.left = Tree('Pepsi')
root.right = Tree('Coke')
root.left.left = Tree('Zero Sugar')
root.left.right = Tree('Cherry Pepsi')
root.right.left = Tree('Sport Drinks')
root.right.left.left = Tree('Powerade')
root.right.left.right = Tree('Dasani')
root.right.left.left.left = Tree('Powerade w/Sugar')

print(root.parent_search('Dasani'))
print(root.parent_search('Dasani')[1])
```

#### Results:

```
('Beverage', 'Coke', 'Sport Drinks')
Coke
```

Comment: Thank you, Stephen, it's short and elegant. My idea with the height isn't really implementable (just curious), in your opinion?

Comment: Anything is implementable. That however does mean you should implement anything. I have some advice I very commonly give to the JR engineers on my team when reviewing code. *The second time you implement something that is almost the same you should could consider combining them. When you get to third time you almost certainly need to put the commonalities into one thing*. If you need a routine that is specifically to get the result specified. Write a wrapper method for your class that calls the more general function and then extracts what is needed. IE: Use code in the last print as a method.

Comment: You already had two traversal routines and were getting ready to write a third.  Instead build one more general routine.  Less code to test, debug, document maintain.

Comment: Thank you, understood, I'm doing a unit testing now!